# Generate a list of dates between two dates

Tags: mysql

I have a table of name with dates. How can I display something like in the second table?

| Name | Date from | date to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Steve | 2021-03-23 | 2021-03-31 |

| Name | Date from | date to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Steve | 2021-03-23 | 2021-03-23 |
| Steve | 2021-03-24 | 2021-03-24 |
| Steve | 2021-03-25 | 2021-03-25 |
| Steve | 2021-03-26 | 2021-03-26 |
| Steve | 2021-03-27 | 2021-03-27 |
| Steve | 2021-03-28 | 2021-03-28 |
| Steve | 2021-03-29 | 2021-03-29 |
| Steve | 2021-03-30 | 2021-03-30 |
| Steve | 2021-03-31 | 2021-03-31 |

Comment: What version are you using? Although, regardless, consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Strawberry I'm Using mysql version 8

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE to repeat from DateFrom to DateTo to get your desired result.

```
with cte as (
  select Name, DateFrom, DateTo from mytable
  union all
  select Name, DateFrom + interval 1 day, DateTo from cte
  where DateFrom < DateTo
)
select Name, DateFrom, DateFrom DateTo from cte
order by DateFrom
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ixAUp62RNNVeF3g5XH8EFg/0)